# Solr query, count of different fields

Tags: solr

Can somebody give an example where Solr query gives the following count result of three fields (google, flickr, yahoo) - where the field value is true ?

```
google:20
flickr:10
yahoo:100
```

from the document like this:

```
{...., google:"123", flickr:"", yahoo:"8910", ....}
```

Thanks in advance.

Cs.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the Terms Component to do that.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

The output is a list of the terms and their document frequency values.

use qt=/terms to call the terms handler, and then specify terms.fl multiple times for each field type

```
terms.fl=google&terms.fl=flicker&terms.fl=yahoo
```

That should give you a count of the "true" term for each of the fields

Comment: Hello Uri, thanks for your quick answer, I made mistake in my question (the problem pops up in my worksplace, but this written at my home) thats why I had to correct my question. The terms values can be "" or "46545163..." (empty string or number represented in string "[0-9]*") I need to count the terms with string numbers